# Probability that $X_k \leq X_i \ \ \ \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\} \setminus k$?

Tags: probability

Given $n$ IID $X_i$. What is the probability that a randomly chosen $X_k$ is smaller than the rest? By symmetry, it should be $\frac{1}{n}$.

But it seems when I compute it with equations, I get $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$. For this approach, I ask what is $P(X_i > X_k)$ where $i \neq k$. By symmetry it is $\frac{1}{2}$. So if we want the other $n-1$ $X$'s to be $> X_k$, isn't the probability $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$? What is wrong with this line of thinking?

Comment: You can only multiply probabilities when the events are independent. Is $\{X_1 > X_2\}$ independent of $\{X_1>X_3\}$ ?

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Aren't they independent because all the $X$'s are independent?

Comment: The point is that $X_1$ is not independent of itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that we're talking about random variables with continuous distribution so that we can ignore the case $X_i=X_k$.

What's wrong with your line of thinking is that
$$
P(X_j>X_k,X_i>X_k)\neq P(X_j>X_k)P(X_i>X_k)
$$ since these two events are *not* independent. They both depend on $X_k$.

Instead
$$
P(X_j>X_k,X_i>X_k)=P(X_j>X_i>X_k)+P(X_i>X_j>X_k)=2\cdot \frac{1}{3!}=\frac{1}{3}
$$
as you wanted, where we've used that the ordering of the $X$'s is a uniform permutation of $\{i,j,k\}$ by your iid assumption.

The calculation for more variables is similar. The number of permutations on $n$ letters starting with a given letter is $\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Ah I see. If instead the question was "what it the probability that all X are greater than some constant $c$." Then in this case, $X_1 > c, X_2 > c, \ldots, X_n > c$ would be independent, right?

Comment: By your assumption of independence, yes. The thing is that telling you that $X_i>X_k$ naturally improves the conditional probability that $X_j>X_k$ (since the information will *sometimes* mean that $X_k$ is small).

Comment: Makes sense. What if $c$ here was replaced by some variable $Y$ that's independent of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$? In this case, the events $X_i > Y$ would NO longer be independent?

Comment: Yes. It would not longer be true that those events are independent.